# About pronouncing the 's' in plural nouns

Tags: grammatical-number, pronunciation, phonology, consonants

A general rule of English pronunciation states that the 's' in plural nouns is to be pronounced as /z/ if it is preceded by a 'voiced consonant' such as /n/ or /g/, and as /s/ if it is preceded by a 'voiceless consonant' such as /t/ or /p/.

Therefore, "pens" is pronounced as /penz/ and "cats" is pronounced as /cats/.

Now my question is, do native speakers of English always follow this rule? Secondly, and this is what I really need to understand, does this rule apply also to the 's' in the verbs of 'third person singular subjects'?

Comment: The important thing to understand is that we don't follow it as if it were a rule. We follow it because it sounds right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes to both your questions.

Native speakers really do follow that “rule” as to whether being next to a vowel or a voiced consonant makes the *-s* suffix voiced as well, whereas being next to an unvoiced consonant makes the suffix also unvoiced.

And secondly, the same phonologic law is in operation when constructing a third-person singular verb.

You can also add a third class to that: forming possessives with apostrophe-*s*.

All three work the same soundwise.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I thought some native speakers did not always follow this rule as I heard them speak on TV and in films. Maybe, I should pay more attention the next time. But for now, I can at least teach my students to follow this rule.

Comment: Indeed. It's always bemused me that English, which has only [nine inflectional morphemes](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Inflection.pdf) left, uses exactly the same suffixes, with exactly the same allomorphy, for **three** of them. German can afford to overload /zi/, because it still has trainloads of inflections. But it's a mark of how little importance we place on inflectional morphology.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, there are no notable groups of speakers that don't follow this rule phonologically: *pens* and *pence,* *tens* and *tense* have different pronunciations for all speakers with typical accents.

One thing that might be causing confusion is that the phoneme /z/ in English is not always fully phonetically voiced. A word like *tens* might be pronounced with a voiceless or partially voiceless fricative, but it still would sound distinct from *tense* because the vowel in *ten* and *tens* would be phonetically longer than the vowel in *tense*. For more details on this, see [Are "whores" and "horse" homophones?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/342273/are-whores-and-horse-homophones) and [The pronunciation of ending "s"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/223160/the-pronunciation-of-ending-s?rq=1).

For a fair number of English speakers, there is a merger in perception (possibly also in production, although I don't know if studies have shown whether it is a complete or partial merger) between /ns, ms/ and /nts, mps/ in many contexts, including word-finally. A smaller number of speakers may merge /ls/ with /lts/. I suppose that, if we analyze the merged pronunciation as containing the phoneme /t/, it would be formally possible to analyze the *tens/tense* contrast as a phonemic contrast of /ns/ vs. /nts/, but I don't think that would be a very convincing analysis.

I haven't heard of any English speakers merging /rs/ with /rts/.