# Why is "wassup" pronounced /ˈwɒsʌp/ but /ˈwɒzʌp/?

Tags: exclamations

Oxford https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/wassup

Collins https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/wassup

"Wassup" stands for "What is up?" and "is" is pronounced "iz" so I think "wassup" should be pronounced /ˈwɒzʌp/. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you really think that "wassup" comes *directly* from "what is up", rather than via "what's up"?

Comment: (Though FWIW, I do often hear it with a [z] sound; it's common in many languages for intervocalic /s/ become voiced.)

Comment: I have never heard anyone say “What is up?” with an actual [ɪz], except that very blonde, white girl from _Not Another Teen Movie_ (I think?) who tries to speak ‘black’ and fails miserably precisely because she says it as three words. If you really think _wassup_ comes from the basically nonexistent “What is up?”, and not from the infinitely more common “What’s up?” (which has an unvoiced [s]), I think you’ll have to dig up some supporting evidence.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet How about this beer commercial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JJmqCKtJnxM

Comment: OK I've got it. Because "wassup" is "what's up" and "what's" is pronounced "/wɑːts/". The next question may be "Why does "what's" end with "s" sound but not "z"?". https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/what-s

Comment: @Emerald214 For the answer to that question, [see here!](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/94820/about-pronouncing-the-s-in-plural-nouns)